# Python nested for-in loops - outermost loop not iterating

Tags: python, csv

Simple problem not sure what's wrong but: I am trying to iterate through two lists which were read from a csv file as follows:

```
for row1 in (list(csv_data1)):
  for row2 in (list(csv_data2)):
    # do something with row2 and row2
```

However after each iteration of the outer for loop, the inner for loop does not recognize that the outer for loop is iterated! For example if I do this:

```
for row1 in (list(csv_data1)):
  for row2 in (list(csv_data2)):
    # do something with row2 and row2
  print row1
```

The elements of row1 get printed properly. However if I try to print the element of the outermost loop within the inner loop like so:

```
for row1 in (list(csv_data1)):
   for row2 in (list(csv_data2)):
     # do something with row2 and row2
     print row1
```

I only get the first row of `(list(csv_data1))` multiple times!

So if `csv_data1 = [['a','b'],['b','c']]` for example, I expect the above print statement (print in inner loop) to print:

```
[['a','b']
# repeated prints of above for however long csv_data2 is ...
['b','c']]
# repeated prints of above for however long csv_data2 is ...
```

But instead I get the following:

```
[['a','b']
# repeated prints of above for however long csv_data2 is ...
['a','b']]
# repeated prints of above for however long csv_data2 is ...
```

I.e. I can't get both loops to iterate through each other. I'm missing something very obvious, any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

## **Edit**: More specifically here is what I am trying to do: (I'm just printing right now to try to diagnose the problem)

```
f1 = open('file1.csv', 'rU')
f2 = open('file2.csv', 'rU')
reader1 = csv.DictReader(f1)
reader2 = csv.DictReader(f2)

# Grab desired columns from csv file
cols_desired = 'district,blockname,villagename'.split(',')

desired_cols_1 = (list(row[col]) for col in cols_desired) for row in reader1)
desired_cols_2 = (list(row[col]) for col in cols_desired) for row in reader2)

for row1 in (list(desired_cols_1)):
  for row2 in (list(desired_cols_2)):
    print row1
    # XXX this prints only the first row of list(desired_cols_1) repeated times for some reason!
```

Comment: Without seeing your code more specifically it's hard to diagnose this.

Comment: Are you doing anything else in your inner for loop, or just printing?

Comment: show us all the lines you reference csv_data1 inside the innermost loop, you must be modifying it, or the inner loop hasn't really ended.

Comment: Hi thanks for your responses. I've updated with more specific code. No I am not modifying anything I believe, just trying to print each element in row1 within the inner loop, but getting the undesired behaviour as in original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a generator for you inner loop. Once you iterate over a generator *once*, the generator is *empty*. So in your first loop, you consume all the elements of `csv_data2`, and then it is empty for all the following loops.

Look at this:

```
>>> x = (i for i in range(5))
>>> y = (i for i in range(5))
>>> for i in x:
...     ylist = list(y)
...     print(id(ylist))
...     print(len(ylist))
...
44917584
5
44917624
0
44918104
0
44918144
0
44918184
0
>>> print(len(list(x)))
0
```

Each iteration creates a new list, and in all but the first iteration, `ylist` is empty. That's because the first iteration *consumes* the generator's elements when it creates the `list`. There's a similar effect on `x`: it's empty after the `for` loop as well. That's what you're seeing.

The solution is to create the `list`s **prior** to the loops:

```
# Square brackets make this a list comprehension instead of a raw generator
# List comprehension gives back a list
desired_cols_1 = [list(row[col]) for col in cols_desired) for row in reader1]
desired_cols_2 = [list(row[col]) for col in cols_desired) for row in reader2]

for row1 in desired_cols_1:
  for row2 in desired_cols_2:
    print row1, row2
```

This will consume the generators only once.

Alternatively, if the data is so large you can't load it all into memory, you could create a new generator for each iteration instead of creating the internal generator prior to the loop:

```
desired_cols_1 = (list(row[col]) for col in cols_desired) for row in reader1)

for row1 in desired_cols_1:
  # Need to make sure the reader is back at the beginning
  reader2.seek(0)
  desired_cols_2 = (list(row[col]) for col in cols_desired) for row in reader2)
  for row2 in desired_cols_2:
    print row1, row2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put the generator in the list call for desired_calls_1 and _2.

```
desired_cols_1 = [ [row[col] for col in cols_desired] for row in reader1 ]
desired_cols_2 = [ [row[col] for col in cols_desired] for row in reader2 ]

for row1 in desired_cols_1:
    for row2 in desired_cols_2:
        print row1
```

My file_1.csv:

```
district,blockname,villagename
a,b,c
e,f,g
```

My file_2.csv:

```
district,blockname,villagename
1,1,1
2,2,2
3,3,3
```

The output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['e', 'f', 'g']
['e', 'f', 'g']
['e', 'f', 'g']
```

Of course, it will print row1 x number of times, where x is len(desired_cols_2). Is that not what you are attempting with your nested for loop?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes that is what I am trying to do at the moment. Your code manages to iterate through desired_cols1 instead of just the first row which is great, however it gets stuck in this infinite loop, when it should stop printing when row1 = last row of desired_cols_1. Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: Could it be that there are a LOT of rows in desired_cols_2  and the output to the console just hasn't caught up yet? What is the len(desired_cols_2)? Can you try it on the test data I added to see if it works for you?

Comment: Yes your test data works :) So it's my csv file that is the problem. The length of desired_cols_2 is 3, the same as desired_cols_1... But there's a lot of data in the csv, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note with for loops in any programming language is you iterate 10 times you are simple saying execute the **same** statements/functions in the for loop until the loop ends

```
for i in ['a','b','c','d']:
    for j in ["hello"]:
        print(j)
```

output

```
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

Hence you can prevent repitition by placing your print statement before the second for loop starts

```
for row1 in (list(desired_cols_1)):
    print row1   
    for row2 in (list(desired_cols_2)):
```